# Automate Webview with INJECT_EVENTS permission

Tags: android, webview

There is this website I need to log into with user and pass every time. I have been using the below code to inject code into the textbox in the website. (after I log in there is still more textboxes I need to fill in which I need automated)

```
wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('SSUser_Logon_0-item-USERNAME').focus();");
wv.evaluateJavascript("try{document.activeElement.value='"+User+"';}catch(e){}",null);
```

I am now getting the error

```
Injecting input events requires the caller (or the source of the instrumentation, if any) to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission.
```

and

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
```

Throws an error that this `permission is only granted to system apps`.

I need help to either inject the code, or find another alternative to automate filling in textboxes on a website.

The code I use to inject is this:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);
```

and gives me the following error:
Injecting input events requires the caller (or the source of the instrumentation, if any) to have the INJECT_EVENTS permission.

Comment: Are you sure the error message is for your app? Neither `loadUrl` nor `evaluateJavascript` functions on webview require the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission

Comment: Yes I get the Requires Inject Events Permission whenever I try to run the above code without the permission

Comment: I mean, could it have come from another part of your app that you haven't shown? Anyway, the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission is `signature` only and there is no way an ordinary app can get that. But for the purposes of "automate filling in textboxes", javascript alone would suffice, and you don't need the `INJECT_EVENTS` permission for that

Comment: I have added the code that I use to inject giving me the requirement

Comment: You cannot use `sendKeyDownUpSync` from a normal app. If you want to submit a form in the HTML, use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit#examples